# NullPointerException while resuming activity

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-fragmentactivity, appcompatactivity

I am getting this crash on a Nexus device (a Sony one with the same OS version does not crash):

```
02-20 14:38:14.551 22255 22255 I DebugActivity: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Handler android.support.v4.app.FragmentHostCallback.getHandler()' on a null object reference
02-20 14:38:14.551 22255 22255 I DebugActivity:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.ensureExecReady(FragmentManager.java:2180)
02-20 14:38:14.551 22255 22255 I DebugActivity:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2233)
02-20 14:38:14.551 22255 22255 I DebugActivity:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:379)
02-20 14:38:14.551 22255 22255 I DebugActivity:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onResume(FragmentActivity.java:461)
02-20 14:38:14.551 22255 22255 I DebugActivity:     at com.whatever.sdk.MyActivity.onResume(MyActivity.java:109)
02-20 14:38:14.551 22255 22255 I DebugActivity:     at com.whatever.sdk.MyActivity$1.onCallStateChanged(MyActivity.java:231)
02-20 14:38:14.551 22255 22255 I DebugActivity:     at android.telephony.PhoneStateListener$2.handleMessage(PhoneStateListener.java:295)
02-20 14:38:14.551 22255 22255 I DebugActivity:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-20 14:38:14.551 22255 22255 I DebugActivity:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
02-20 14:38:14.551 22255 22255 I DebugActivity:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
02-20 14:38:14.551 22255 22255 I DebugActivity:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-20 14:38:14.551 22255 22255 I DebugActivity:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
02-20 14:38:14.551 22255 22255 I DebugActivity:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

And here is the relevant piece of code:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
...
    private final PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
            if(state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE) {
                MyActivity.this.onResume();
...
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        try {
            super.onResume();
...
```

The activity is not declared with any launchMode and trying to add different flags such as `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` when starting the activity did not help. We have `supportLibraryVersion = '27.0.2'`

*Is there an obvious fix to this and why is it happening on some devices and not on others?*

Comment: You shouldn't be calling `onResume()`; that's a framework lifecycle method and only the Android framework should call it. But I can't really say how to "fix" this, since I don't know what you're _really_ trying to do when `onCallStateChanged()` is called.

Comment: What are you trying to do in `onCallStateChanged()`?

Comment: This is legacy code from an ex-employee; according to git logs, he was trying to pause/resume the activity (which is playing video) during phone calls.

Comment: `TelephonyManager mgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            if (mgr != null) 
                mgr.listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit to @ben-p's comment for the [undocumented info](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onResume()) on "only the Android framework should call [onResume()]" (mind you, this is a public method, along with [onPostResume](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html#onPostResume())), the solution was to remove `phoneStateListener`. Testing on the emulator, it is clear that the activity (and the video it hosts) is correctly paused and resumed by the framework when an incoming call notification is received and when the notification is dismissed or when the user finishes the phone call. The confusing part is that on most devices, calling `onResume()` directly *does not* lead to a crash, hiding the bug.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling Android lifecycle method like `onResume()` in `onCallStateChanged()` just remove the relevant code of `onResume()` in a separate method and call that method from `onCallStateChanged()`. That way when the Activity will resume the relevant code gets called and also when needed you can call that method to run the relevant code. Ofcourse you will need to add appropriate object condition checking in this newly created method.

Comment: could you provide code for "appropriate object condition checking"? e.g. what is blah() in `private void resume() {  if (blah()) ... }`

Comment: this you should try to find in the current onResume() method

Comment: I included onResume in my question, the crash is happening within super.onResume() - what should I check for there?

Comment: I am saying to put the codes in onResume() in a separate method. Then call that method as you need within your activity. I guess the problem is not within super.onResume(). It's about not having the appropriate reference of MainActivity and/or what @Ben P. mentioned

Answer (score 0):

From the error log I can see you are working with Fragments. I have encountered similar error before. One other thing comes to mind is saving a reference to your MainActivity e.g in Fragments in a reference like `Activity mainActivityRef = getActivity()`. Later try to use this as `mainActivityRef.onMyFunc()`. This has saved me from this error `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Handler android.support.v4.app.FragmentHostCallback.getHandler()' on a null object reference`

Comment: I'm not using fragments, AppCompatActivity does it under the hood within the support library. Could you provide some code though?